# OpenCV 3.2 Make Error

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, makefile, cmake, opencv3.2

- OpenCV => 3.2
- Operating System / Platform => Ubuntu 64 bit
- Compiler => make

Detailed description

I am having some trouble installing OpenCV 3.2. I followed the example given on Milq's github: https://github.com/milq/milq/blob/master/scripts/bash/install-opencv.sh; however upon typing the command "make -j4", the process stopped at 23% due to a make error. I then tried this solution: http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation, using the same OpenCV 3.2 zip file from the first solution. However, it stopped again, and I got the following error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_cudaarithm
[ 18%] [ 18%] [ 18%] [ 18%] Building CXX object 
modules/cudaarithm/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudaarithm.dir/src/core.cpp.o
Building CXX object modules /cudaarithm/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudaarithm.dir/src/element_operations.cpp.o
Building CXX object modules/cudaarithm/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudaarithm.dir/src/reductions.cpp.o
Building CXX object modules/cudaarithm/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudaarithm.dir/src/arithm.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so
[ 18%] Built target opencv_cudaarithm
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone have any suggestion or solution to fix this? I have tried recreating it nearly 5 times, and everytime I receive the same error. I believe it has something to do with cudaarithm. I am pretty new to these types of installations, but I trying my best to learn. I have been able to figure out most things myself and by trial and error, but I am at a loss here.